# How to write the below linq query without using many if conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am filtering the employee data based on cascading dropdowns. If the value of the parameter is '-1', it means 'all data'. for example, if departmentid = -1 then the user have selected all in the drop-down, and similarly for category and role.

Now I need to query the database using EF linq queries. I have three foreign key associations in my employee entity to get the name of the job category, role, and department based on the selected value.

So, if the user has selected -1 (all) for category and job role, it has to query the employee entity and bring back all the employees in the selected department else it should filter based on selected department, or category or role.

I'm not sure how to write a concise linq query for this without using three or if-else statements. Below is what I have so far, but if I take this approach, I need to use at least another three if statements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetEmployees(Models.Department department, Models.Category      category, Models.Role role)
    {
        try
        {
           if (department.DepId == -1)
            {
                using (emsCtx)
                {
                    var allResults = (from q in emsCtx.Employees
                                      select new Models.Employee
                                      {
                                      Id = q.Id,
                                      FirstName = q.FirstName,
                                      MiddleName = q.MiddleName,
                                      LastName = q.Lastname,
                                      DOB = q.DOB,
                                      JobTitle = q.Roles.Designation,
                                      JobCategory = q.Categories.Type,
                                      Department = q.Departments.Name,
                                      Salary = q.BasicPay 
                                      }).ToList();
                    employeeData.Employees = allResults;
                }
            }
            else
            using (emsCtx)
            {
                var empResults = (from q in emsCtx.Employees
                                  where department.DepId == q.Department 
                                  && role.RoleId == q.Designation
                                  && category.CatId == q.Category
                                  select new Models.Employee
                                  {
                                      Id = q.Id,
                                      FirstName = q.FirstName,
                                      MiddleName = q.MiddleName,
                                      LastName = q.Lastname,
                                      DOB = q.DOB,
                                      JobTitle = q.Roles.Designation,
                                      JobCategory = q.Categories.Type,
                                      Department = q.Departments.Name,
                                      Salary = q.BasicPay 
                                  }).ToList();
                employeeData.Employees = empResults;
            }
            return View(employeeData);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your Main LINQ expression like below :

```
from q in emsCtx.Employees
where (department.DepId == -1 ? true : (department.DepId == q.Department 
                                        && role.RoleId == q.Designation
                                        && category.CatId == q.Category))
select new Models.Employee
```

This will fix your concern.

Comment: Thanks..Could you please let me know how to write your above query if I have to check whether the RoleId or CatId = -1 ? This is because I need to check for other combinations like  "All departments, All Categories, Selected role", "All Departments, Selected Category, Selected Role", etc..Could you please help ?